# How to inform client about progress on the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, progress

I'm generating PDF files on the server. I want to implement a progress bar on the client side, so a user will have some  idea how long that operation will take. Making a progress bar for files that are being uploaded is pretty straight forward, but I have no idea how long it takes to generate the PDF on the backend.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a request for the file, you could return a token from the app and from your frontend periodically query for whether a job with a given token is done/how far along it is.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help! Should I store tokens with their progress in the database?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to. If you use sessions you could also store its id along with the token and check whether it matches the progress request.